# Listing multiple fields to be dropped at once in QGIS modeler?

Tags: algorithm, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to drop more than one fields at once in QGIS 3 modeler on Microsoft Windows. I'm using the algorithm "Drop field(s)".

What is the good syntax to list multiple fields to be dropped?

Not working:
'Field1','Field2','Field3'

"Field1","Field2","Field3"

When I run it, I get a python error and the result is empty, no column at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to separate them via semi-colons:

```
field1;field2;field3
```