# Drop multiple fields in graphic modeller qgis 3.10.14 not working

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I am trying to use the graphical modeler to delete multiple fields in QGIS 3.10.14.

[image]

When i try to use the ***Drop Fields*** algorithm to delete multiple fields from the required layer, it deletes only the first field and not all the specified fields.
[image]

From the console result it states that the other fields not deleted don't exist.

[image]

I tried using different delimiters to separate each value i.e. ***comma***, ***semicolon***. It did not work either.

However if I run the Drop Fields multiple times, it removes all field in each of the operations.

[image]

So will it be possible to delete the fields in one operation?

Comment: Does the semicolon without spaces work as here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303760/listing-multiple-fields-to-be-dropped-at-once-in-qgis-modeler?

Comment: @user30184 
Just tried your suggestion and that solves it.

Comment: @BERA I was using Refactor fields previously to manually to remove the unwanted columns. I have been able to get it to work based on the suggestion of user30184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion (solution) from @user30184, removing the spaces between the field names i.e. **offset;instance;cat**

[image]

and not ***offset; instance; cat***

[image]

solves the problem. As such it produces the result I wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Processing Toolbox, for "Fields to drop" choose "Pre-Calculated Value" and enter field names without spaces, semicolon delimited, all enclosed in single quotes

[image: QGIS Drop field(2) GUI]